# Use 'groupby' on statistically processed R2 values- python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

For my research I have a specific calculation for R2 values. It is not an R2 value directly calculated using Linregress function.

The code I am using is for statistically processed R2 value (labelled as 'best R2). I get the R2 value for entire x and y axis. However, there are multiple 'Test Events' in the data. This means I need R2 value for Individual 'Test event'

Code I am using until now to calculate R2 values (and what I need the output to be) is as follows:

---

```
import numpy, scipy,pandas as pd, matplotlib
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats
import copy
df=pd.read_excel("I:/Python/Excel.xlsx")
df.head()

xyDataPairs = df[['x', 'y']].values.tolist()

minDataPoints = len(xyDataPairs) - 1
# utility function
def UniqueCombinations(items, n):
    if n==0:
        yield []
    else:
        for i in range(len(items)):
            for cc in UniqueCombinations(items[i+1:],n-1):
                yield [items[i]]+cc

bestR2 = 0.0
bestDataPairCombination = []
bestParameters = []

for pairs in UniqueCombinations(xyDataPairs, minDataPoints):
    x = []
    y = []
    for pair in pairs:
        x.append(pair[0])
        y.append(pair[1])
    fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(x, y, 1) # straight line
    modelPredictions = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, x)
    absError = modelPredictions - y
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(y))
    if Rsquared > bestR2:
        bestR2 = Rsquared
        bestDataPairCombination = copy.deepcopy(pairs)
        bestParameters = copy.deepcopy(fittedParameters)
    print('best R2', bestR2)
```

The above best R2 value is for entire x and y columns.
However, say I have to split the entire data set into four events                    each event has it's own R2 value. Then how do I get it?
I need to get the above code give me 'bestR2' values with 'groupby' with respect to 'Test Event.
 It is an R2 value which is highly processed to suit the results I needed for my research project.
Thus direct usage of Linregress won't help and this is the reason I calculated bestR2 differently.
In short: I need the best R2 value for multiple test events as calculated by above method.

---

Result should be as follows:

```
Test_Event  best R2
1           0.999
2           0.547
3           0.845
4           0.784
```

Thanks for reading!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by 'test_event' column, and apply a custom function to compute the best_r2 value for each group. The custom function is simply a wrapper over your desired logic (here called `compute_best_r2`).

Following is a working solution:

```
import numpy, pandas as pd
import copy

df=pd.read_excel("...")

def UniqueCombinations(items, n):
    if n==0:
        yield []
    else:
        for i in range(len(items)):
            for cc in UniqueCombinations(items[i+1:],n-1):
                yield [items[i]]+cc


def compute_best_r2(data):
    xyDataPairs = data[['x', 'y']].values.tolist()
    minDataPoints = len(xyDataPairs)
    bestR2 = 0.0
    bestDataPairCombination = []
    bestParameters = []

    for pairs in UniqueCombinations(xyDataPairs, minDataPoints):
        x = []
        y = []
        for pair in pairs:
            x.append(pair[0])
            y.append(pair[1])
        fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(x, y, 1) # straight line
        modelPredictions = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, x)
        absError = modelPredictions - y
        Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(y))
        if Rsquared > bestR2:
            bestR2 = Rsquared
            bestDataPairCombination = copy.deepcopy(pairs)
            bestParameters = copy.deepcopy(fittedParameters)
    data['best_r2'] = bestR2
    return data

df_with_best_r2 = df.groupby(['test_event']).apply(compute_best_r2)
result = df_with_best_r2[['test_event', 'best_r2']].groupby(['test_event']).agg(['first']).reset_index()[['test_event', 'best_r2']]
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(-1)
```

Note that I changed `minDataPoints` to `len(xyDataPairs)` instead of `len(xyDataPairs) - 1` as it seemed like a bug, please make sure that's what you intended.

I tested it with this sample data:

```
test_event  x   y
1          1.5  2
1          1    1.8
1          2    4
1          2    6
2          1    1
2          2    2
```

Which result with:

```
   test_event   best_r2
0           1  0.705464
1           2  1.000000
```